# Authentication (Register) in next.js. How to send data to the server?

Tags: laravel, next.js

I am trying to make a user registration function, I have already defined all the states, the endpoint is right but still the front end data does not arrive to the server, I don't know what is going on. In React.js everything was working, I just migrated to Next.js and this function doesn't work anymore.

I am doing it this way :

My code in Next.js :

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

// calling the rest api
import axios from '../api/axios';

//icons
import { HiOutlineArrowNarrowLeft } from 'react-icons/hi';
import { AiOutlineArrowLeft, AiOutlineArrowRight } from 'react-icons/ai';

// imgs
import logo from '../assets/logostreaming.png';
import ManLogin from '../assets/man_login.png';
import WomanLogin from '../assets/woman_login.png';
import UserCircle from '../assets/UserCircle.png';

//styles
import styles from '../styles/signup.module.css';

const Signup = () => {
    const navigate = useRouter();

    // states
    const [nif, setNif] = useState('');
    const [codPin, setCodPin] = useState('');
    const [photoProfile, setPhotoProfile] = useState('');
    const [sex, setSex] = useState('');
    const [nameUser, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
    const [whatsApp, setWhatsApp] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [dateBirth, setDateBirth] = useState('');
    const [codPartners, setCodePartners] = useState(0);
    const [confirmationPassword, setConfirmationPassword] = useState('');
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const [querySelector, setQuerySelector] = useState('close');
    const [firstStep, setFirstStep] = useState(true);
    const [secondStep, setSecondStep] = useState(false);
    const [TreeStep, setTreeStep] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        setPhotoProfile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
    const handleRegister = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const config = {
            headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        }

        if (photoProfile == '') {
            setError(true);
        }

        axios.post('/register/',
            {
                email: email, password: password, phone: phone,
                nif: nif, whatsApp: whatsApp, date_birth: dateBirth,
                partners_code: codPartners, sex: sex, name: nameUser,
                cod_pin: codPin, photo_profile: photoProfile, permission: 1,
                c_password: confirmationPassword, obs: 'null'
            }, config
        )
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('data res signup register : ', res.data.data);
                const id = res.data.data.user.id;
                localStorage.setItem('userId', id);
                const token = res.data.data.token;
                const permission = res.data.data.user.permission;
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                localStorage.setItem('permission', permission);
                axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                navigate.push('/client/home');
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log('erro na promise signup register : ', err))
            .finally();

    }

    const QSelector = () => {
        setQuerySelector('open')
    }

    const QSelectorClose = () => {
        setQuerySelector('close');
        console.log('query selector close : ', querySelector);
    }

    const nextStep1 = () => {
        //e.preventDefault();
        if (nameUser == '' || sex == '' || whatsApp == '' || phone == '' || dateBirth == '') {
            setError(true);
        } else {
            setFirstStep(false);
            setSecondStep(true);
            setTreeStep(false);
        }
    }
    const backToStep1 = () => {
        //e.preventDefault();
        setFirstStep(true);
        setSecondStep(false);
        setTreeStep(false)

    }
    const nextStep2 = () => {
        //e.preventDefault();
        if (nif == '' || codPin == '' || password == '' || confirmationPassword == '' || email == '') {
            setError(true);
        } else {
            setFirstStep(false);
            setSecondStep(false);
            setTreeStep(true);

        }
    }



    return (
        <div className={styles.container_register}>
            <header className={styles.header_register}>
                <Image className={styles.Image_logo_register} src={logo} alt="logo pn clique streaming" />
                <nav>
                    <label><HiOutlineArrowNarrowLeft /></label>
                    <label onClick={() => navigate.push('/')}>Voltar para a página inicial</label>
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div className={styles.container_form}>
                <form encType='multipart/form-data' onSubmit={handleRegister} className={styles.form_register}>
                    {
                        error
                            ?
                            <div className={styles.error_form}>
                                <p>Por favor preencha todos os campos para continuar!</p>
                            </div>
                            : ''
                    }
                    {
                        firstStep
                            ?
                            <div className={styles.container_first_form}>
                                <Image className={styles.Image_man_register} src={ManLogin} alt="clique man register" />
                                <div className={styles.container_first_form_div}>
                                    <strong className={styles.title_register}>Dados pessoias</strong>
                                    <p className={styles.slogan}>Registre-se para usufruir dos nossos serviços.</p>
                                    <nav>
                                        <input type="text" name='name' className={styles.input_register} placeholder='Digite o seu nome' value={nameUser} onChange={(e) => [setName(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                        <div className={styles.select_wrapper_register}>
                                            <div className={querySelector == 'close' ? styles.select_sex : styles.select_sex_open}>
                                                <div className={styles.select__trigger} onClick={() => querySelector == 'close' ? QSelector() : QSelectorClose()}>
                                                    <span>{sex == '' ? 'Qual é o seu sexo ?' : sex}</span>
                                                    <div className={styles.arrow}></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className={styles.custom_options} onClick={() => QSelectorClose()} >
                                                    <span onClick={() => setSex('Homem')}>Homem</span>
                                                    <span onClick={() => setSex('Mulher')}>Mulher</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" name='whatsApp' className={styles.input_register} placeholder='Digite o seu whatsApp' value={whatsApp} onChange={(e) => [setWhatsApp(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                        <input type="text" name='phone' className={styles.input_register} placeholder='Digite um número alternativo' value={phone} onChange={(e) => [setPhone(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                        <input type="text" name='date_birth' className={styles.input_register_date_birth} placeholder='Data de nascimento (dd/mm/aa)' value={dateBirth} onChange={(e) => [setDateBirth(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                    </nav>
                                    <button type='button' className={styles.btn_next_step_register} onClick={nextStep1}>Próximo <AiOutlineArrowRight className={styles.AiOutlineArrowRight} /></button>
                                </div>
                                <Image className={styles.Image_woman_register} src={WomanLogin} alt="clique man register" />
                            </div>
                            :
                            secondStep
                                ?
                                <div className={styles.container_first_form}>
                                    <Image className={styles.Image_man_register} src={ManLogin} alt="clique man register" />
                                    <div className={styles.container_first_form_div}>
                                        <strong className={styles.title_register}>Dados de segurança</strong>
                                        <p className={styles.slogan_2}>Torna a tua conta mais segura.</p>
                                        <nav>
                                            <input type="text" name='nif' className={styles.input_register} placeholder='Digite o seu nif' value={nif} onChange={(e) => [setNif(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                            <input type="text" name='cod_pin' className={styles.input_register} placeholder='Digite o seu codigo pin' value={codPin} onChange={(e) => [setCodPin(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                            <input type="password" name='password' className={styles.input_register} placeholder='Digite a sua senha' value={password} onChange={(e) => [setPassword(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                            <input type="password" name='c_password' className={styles.input_register_c_password} placeholder='Confirma a sua senha' value={confirmationPassword} onChange={(e) => [setConfirmationPassword(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                            <input type="email" name='email' className={styles.input_register_date_birth} placeholder='Digite o seu email' value={email} onChange={(e) => [setEmail(e.target.value), setError('')]} />
                                        </nav>
                                        <div className={styles.container_buttons_register}>
                                            <button type='button' className={styles.btn_next_step_register_2} onClick={backToStep1}><AiOutlineArrowLeft className={styles.AiOutlineArrowRight_2} /> Voltar</button>
                                            <button type='button' className={styles.btn_next_step_register_2} onClick={nextStep2}>Próximo <AiOutlineArrowRight className={styles.AiOutlineArrowRight_3} /></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                :
                                TreeStep
                                    ?
                                    <div className={styles.container_first_form}>
                                        <div className={styles.container_first_form_div}>
                                            <strong className={styles.title_register}>Foto de perfil</strong>
                                            <p className={styles.slogan_2}>Seleciona uma foto de perfil.</p>

                                            <div className={styles.container_first_form_div_2}>
                                                <label htmlFor="photo_profile">
                                                    <Image className={styles.Image_user_circle_register} src={UserCircle} alt="clique man register" />
                                                </label>
                                                <input type="file" id='photo_profile' name='photo_profile' className={styles.input_register_file} placeholder='Photo' onChange={(e) => [handleFileChange(e), setError('')]} />
                                                <label>Seleciona  uma foto de perfil</label>
                                                <label className={styles.partners}>Deseja se tornar um parceiro ? <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={checked} onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)} name="partners" /></label>
                                                <button className={styles.button_register} type='submit' onMouseOver={() => sex == '' ? setSex('Homem') : setSex(sex)}>Registrar</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <Image className={styles.Image_woman_register} src={WomanLogin} alt="clique man register" />
                                    </div>
                                    : ''
                    }





                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

}

export default Signup;
```

My code in Laravel (server) :

```
class RegisterController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Register api
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $n = $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        $e = $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);
        
        if ($n->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation name register Error.', $validator->errors());
        }

        if ($e->fails()) {
            return $this->sendError('Validation email register Error.', $validator->errors());
        }

        $uploadFolder = 'users';
        $image = $request->file('photo_profile');
        $image_uploaded_path = $image->store($uploadFolder, 'public');
        $uploadedImageResponse = Storage::url($image_uploaded_path);
        //$input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $input['photo_profile'] = $uploadedImageResponse;
        $user = User::create($input);
        $sucess['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->plainTextToken;
        $sucess['user'] = $user;

        if ($user->permission == 2 || $user->permission == 3) {
            AccountStatus::create(['user_id' =>  $user->id, 'active' => 1]);
            AccountBalance::create([
                'user_id' =>  $user->id,
                'current_balance' => '0',
                'points_accumulated' => 0
            ]);
            CreateSuggestion::create(['user_id' =>  $user->id, 'account_service_id' => 1]);
        }


        return $this->sendResponse($sucess, 'User Register with successfully.');
    }`
```

Comment: try to add full url in  axios call.  because they are running in different instances. 

eg: axios.post('http://localhost:8080/register/');

Laravel (server) if you running a MVC application not required to mention complete path

Comment: 2 question and one suggestion: first question: is the laravel route registered as an API or as a Web ? second question: are they in the same laravel project or is the nuxt.js built separately?, suggestion: in the validation part of your code please use `$request = $request->validate([ 'name' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email' ], [ 'name.required' => 'Name validation error', 'email.required' => 'Email validation error' ]);`